# Showing that if $\forall n \ge 0: \int_{-1}^{1} f(t)t^{2n+1} dt = 0$ and $f$ is continuous, then $f$ must be even

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

I am trying to prove the following problem:

> Suppose that $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and for sufficiently large $n$, we have
>
> $$ \int_{-1}^{1} f(t)t^{2n+1} dt =0$$
>
> Show that $f$ is even.

I believe I have seen a similar problem before, and the solution inovolved some manipulations like I do above. However, I'm unable to come up with the complete solution. I do not remember clearly, but the solution may or may not involve the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem.

**My Attempt:** Instead of "sufficiently large $n$", we can assume $n \ge 0$. It is easy to generalize later.

Using the substitution $t \mapsto -t$, we get that
$$\int_{-1}^1 f(-t) t^{2n+1}.$$
Subtracting the two integrals gives
$$\int_{-1}^1[f(t)-f(-t)] t^{2n+1} dt=0$$

Let $g(t) =  f(t)-f(-t)$. This function $g$ is in fact odd. However, I'm not sure what to do after this point.

Comment: More than that, use the linear independence of $t^{2n+1}$ for any $n$ to show that $g=0$, then you are done.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm sorry, could you give a little more detail? I'm not sure how to proceed with your hint.

Comment: Do you know the Stone-Weirstrass theorem ?

Comment: @CHAMSI Yes ${}{}$

Comment: @CHAMSI I'm fine with a solution using Stone-Weierstrass, but do you think it's possible to do it without? I fear that the answer is no, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well use it to prove that $ g=0 $, first of all, since $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \int_{-1}^{1}{g\left(t\right)t^{2n+1}\,\mathrm{d}t}=0 $, for every odd polynomial $ P $, we have $ \int_{-1}^{1}{g\left(t\right)P\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}=0 $. By the Stone-Weirstrass theorem, there exists some sequence of odd polynomials $ \left(P_{n}\right)_{n} $ that converges uniformly to $ g $.

Let $ \varepsilon>0 $.

$$\left|\int_{-1}^{1}{g^{2}\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\right|\leq\left|\int_{-1}^{1}{g^{2}\left(t\right)}-\int_{-1}^{1}{g\left(t\right)P_{n}\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\right|$$

Comment: \begin{aligned} &\leq\int_{-1}^{1}{f\left(t\right)\left|g\left(t\right)\right|\left\Vert g-P_{n}\right\Vert_{\infty}\mathrm{d}t}\\ &\leq\varepsilon\int_{-1}^{1}{\left|g\left(t\right)\right|\mathrm{d}t} \end{aligned}

Thus $$ \int_{-1}^{1}{g^{2}\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}=0 $$ Meaning $ g=0 \cdot $

Comment: @CHAMSI But the set of odd polynomials is not closed under multiplication (ex. $x \cdot x = x^2)$, so it is not an algebra.

Comment: But if we separate off a $t$ and use even polynomials we do get an algebra, but it doesn't separate points on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: We have forced the $ P_{n} $'s to be odd, because $ g $ is odd.

Since $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ \int_{-1}^{1}{g\left(t\right)t^{2n+1}\,\mathrm{d}t}=0 $, by linearity $ \int_{-1}^{1}{f\left(t\right)\sum_{k=0}^{p}{a_{k}x^{2k+1}}\,\mathrm{d}t}=0 $, $ p\in\mathbb{N} $, $ \left(a_{n}\right)_{n}\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \cdot $

Comment: @CHAMSI Yes, I agree with that, but the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem requires the space of functions that we use to be an algebra, separate points, and vanish nowhere. The set of odd polynomials is not an algebra, so I don't think we can get a uniformly convergent sequence of odd polynomials convering to $g$ from Stone-W alone.

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought every continuous function defined on some segment $ \left[a,b\right] $, can be approximated that way. The stone-Weirstrass theorem only requires the function to be continuous. Isn't it ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem

Comment: @CHAMSI Yes $f$ is only required to be continuous. The additional restrictions are placed on the space from which we approximate $f$. Your link points to the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem (which is technically not the same as the stone Weierstrass Theorem). The Weierstrass Approximation Theorem says that we may find a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $f$. But it does not guarantee that we can find a sequence consiting of odd polynomials. The Stone-Weierstrass theorem generalizes this; it guarantees us a sequence converging unif. to $f$ from many other sets of functions, ...

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @CHAMSI ... not only from the set of polynomials. If you have any set of continuous functions $S$ which is $1)$ an algebra $2)$ separates points and $3)$ vanishes nowhere, then you can find a uniformly convergent sequence of functions converging to $f$.

Comment: @CHAMSI Sure, my pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To simplify the whole discussion above: take $(P_n)$ a sequence of polynomials that converges uniformly to $f$. Consider $Q_n(t) = P_n(t) - P_n(-t)$, and $g(t) = f(t) - f(-t)$. Then $(Q_n)$ is a sequence of polynomials with all coefficients of even degree vanishing, and which converges to $g$. By assumption and linearity, we have
$$
\int_{-1}^1 Q_n(t) f(t) \: \mathrm{d} t = 0,
$$
and by substitution $t \mapsto -t$,
$$
\int_{-1}^1 Q_n(t) f(-t) \: \mathrm{d} t = 0,
$$
so finally
$$
\int_{-1}^1 Q_n(t) g(t) \: \mathrm{d} t = 0.
$$
By taking a uniform limit, this gives
$$
\int_{-1}^1 g^2(t) \: \mathrm{d} t = 0,
$$
so $g = 0$, which means that $f$ is even.

Comment: Very nice, thanks!

Comment: I suppose it's likely unfeasible to do this just using basic calculus (no Stone-W.), right?

Comment: I do not suppose so. It is a version of the classical exercise *if $f$ is continuous and $\int_a^b f(t) t^n \: \mathrm{d} t = 0$ for all $n$, then $f = 0$", and I've only saw it done with Weierstrass.

Comment: Actually, both statements are pretty much equivalent. If you look in $H=L^2([-1,1])$, and take $E \subset H$, then saying that $E$ is dense in $H$ is the same as saying that $E^{\perp} = 0$. In other words: "$E$ is dense" if and only if "$\int_{-1}^1 fg = 0$ for all $g \in E$ implies $f = 0$".

Comment: Ah, thanks for the interesting take